# Save Compiled GLSL Binary with OpenGL ES on iOS

Tags: ios, opengl-es, glsl

I am working with some complicated shaders that take up to 5 or so seconds to compile on iOS devices. The shaders have been highly optimized to reduce the running time of the app but the more optimized they became, the longer the compile time got.

I am wondering if there is a way to save the compiled version of the shader to load after the first run, instead of compiling it every time the app is run. Any ideas on how to approach this would be very useful.

I believe OpenGL 4.1 has an extension called "ARB_get_program_binary" which allows something like this to be done but that is definitely not an option for iOS anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OpenGL ES 2 has getting shader binary in its core specification.

But the problem with iOS implementation of OpenGL ES is that it doesn't export any binary formats. Meaning glGetInteger(GL_NUM_SHADER_BINARY_FORMATS) returns 0.

So no luck on iOS with binary shader format.

Answer (score -1):

Until iOS 8 and OpenGL ES 3.0, there is no way to do this.